# Can't run two separated sites under the same NGINX server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

I'm trying to run two separated sites on the same server using nginx.
Depending of the configuration, nginx serves one site or another under both domain names. It won't run each site on it's own domain.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update:** I've tried Michael Hampton's suggestion, but the server doesn't start when there are two server_name directives. If I comment one of then, nginx starts, but running just one website.

Also `service nginx configtest` just works with only one server_name, with two server_name it fails.

The configuration files follow:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/joomla

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name n-pix.com;

    root /var/www/n-pix;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

    error_log    /var/log/nginx/joomla.error.log info;

    # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    client_max_body_size 1024M;

    server_tokens off;

    # deny running scripts inside writable directories
    location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
            return 403;
            error_page 403 /403_error.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # caching of files 
    location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
            expires 1y;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
            expires 14d;
    }

}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/jarbas

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.jarbas.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name jarbas.n-pix.com;

  root /home/deployer/apps/jarbas/current/public;

  error_log    /var/log/nginx/jarbas.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 1G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: After updating the configuration files, I ran `nginx -t`:

`nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused your `listen` and `server_name` directives.

`listen` should contain the port (and optionally IP/IPv6 address) that you want the server to listen on.

`server_name` should contain the hostname of the server.

For instance (this config requires nginx 1.3.4 or higher):

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name n-pix.com;
```

and

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name jarbas.n-pix.com;
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but the server doesn't start when there are two `server_name` on the config files. If I comment one of then, nginx starts, but running just one website.

Comment: You have to put them in the correct `server` blocks!

Comment: Also `service nginx configtest` just works with only one `server_name` , with two `server_name` it fails.

Comment: I know. I updated my config files on the question. Take a look there.

Comment: You forgot to specify what the problems were with your configuration.

Comment: I don't receive any error message when I try to start nginx with the new configuration. It only doesn't start. I've tried error_log on debug level, but nothing there.

Comment: Any idea, Michael?

Answer (score 1):

After updating the configuration files, I ran `nginx -t`:

```
nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

so I added `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;` to `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    (...)

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    (...)
}
```

And everything works well now. Thanks guys!